# How to get Id inside <form> for testing using click method

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-5

I tried to get the id from my html to used by `click` method in unit testing laravel.

here is my html using blade:

```
<td>
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ action('AdminWeb\UserController@toggleActivateStatus', $user->id) }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <button id="user{{$user->id}}" class="btn btn-sm {{ $user->status == 'active' ? 'btn-danger' : 'btn-success' }}" type="submit">{{ $user->status == 'active' ? 'Deactivate' : 'Activate' }}</button>
    </form>
</td>
```

notice that I generate the id element in `<button>` using `id="user{{$user->id}}"`

so I tried to get that id for example `id=user3` in my test class like this :

```
public function testActivateUser()
  {
    $this->visit('users')
      ->click('user3')
      ->seePageis('users');
  }
```

but I unable to get it :

```
UserControllerTest::testActivateUser
InvalidArgumentException: Could not find a link with a body, name, or ID attribute of [user3].
```

any help? thanks.

Comment: What about making a hidden input with the user id and place the 'name' tag as 'user3'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click method does not work with buttons, as the exception says, it only works with links. You can try the following:

```
...
    <form>
        <button name="activate-user-{{ $user->id }}"></button>
    </form>
...
```

and within your test

```
/**
 * A basic user activation test.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function testActivateUser()
{
    $this->visit('/users')->press('activate-user-1');
}
```